# What does this hammer icon next to Roblox usernames mean?

Tags: roblox

What does this symbol/icon next to a username mean?

[image: a white hammer on a gray background]

Answer (score 5):

Source: [Roblox Playerlist Updates](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/playerlist-updates/434738?page=11)

It's the new owner icon. It means they own the game they are in.

Comment: It can also mean that they have editing permissions on that game they are in.